# How could you change the number day of the year to an actual date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, calendar

I have the day 334 or November 29th(on a leap year). Is there a method I can use to change this to an actual date or will I have to write a program? I"m looking for the method 'yday' backward, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`Date::ordinal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-ordinal):

```
require 'date'

Date.ordinal(2014, 334) #=> #<Date: 2014-11-30 ((2456992j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.ordinal(2016, 334) #=> #<Date: 2016-11-29 ((2457722j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
require 'date'

Date.new(2014)+334-1 #=> #<Date: 2014-11-30 ((2456992j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
Date.new(2016)+334-1 #=> #<Date: 2016-11-29 ((2457722j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strptime/class) will be helpful to you.

```
Date.strptime('2014-334', '%Y-%j')
```

should return 2014-11-29